# jquery.validate: Validating three fields, values should be unique

Tags: jquery, validation

I have three fields:

```
<input name="answerOne">
<input name="answerTwo"> 
<input name="answerThree">
```

I would like to create add a method in jquery.validate where it operates like the equalTo method. The values of each of the input texts **must** be unique. Also, I would like to re-validate the other fields and check if they have unique values and remove the error if it is unique.

Example Scenario:

1.

answerOne value = abc

answerTwo value = asd

answerThree value = qwe

No errors should occur

2.

answerOne value = abc

answerTwo value = abc

answerThree value = qwe

AnswerTwo should have an error

3.

answerOne value = fgh

answerTwo value = abc

answerThree value = qwe

AnswerTwo's error should be gone

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate() {
    return ($("input[name=answerOne]").val() != $("input[name=answerTwo]").val() && $("input[name=answerOne]").val() != $("input[name=answerThree]").val() && $("input[name=answerTwo]").val() != $("input[name=answerThree]").val())
}
```

if the function returns false then it's not valid.

Comment: This does not use the jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a rule built into the base jQuery Validation library, so your best bet may be to create a custom rule to handle it.  I found this example of someone who created one that looks like what you're asking for:

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2010/05/24/jquery-validator-plugin-and-notequalto-rule-with-multiple-fields/